# Update query only updating data with first letter of new value

Tags: sql, vba, sql-update

In an Access Database, I'm trying to run an update query that fixes Y/N's to be Yes and No. This is done via VBA.

I've checked the query I wrote in VBA by putting it in the query editor, I get similar results.

In VBA, I run the following command

```
db.Execute "Update tblChecks Set NCR = 'No' where NCR = ' ' or NCR is null"
```

This updates all blank and null records to "N" rather than "No"

No error messages are produced, the query runs, but it's only taking the first letter of anything I put in the Set criteria. I've tested this with other criteria such as "Yes" and "Test" and I get "Y" and "T" respectively in those rows.

Comment: what's your NCR db length?

Comment: It was 1.. that makes so much more sense. Thanks! I'm just surprised since it was short text and I didn't think it ever went to 1 as the field length. Is there an easy way to update all short text fields to have max size for short text? I'm trying to think of the possible downsides of doing that, but I don't really know if there are any.

Comment: Updating all fields should be a new question. Downsides: if you limit to a size smaller than 255, you can  never exceed that (e.g. city name with 200 chars ), even not by accident.

Answer (score 2):

Text field size of your column "`NCR"` should not be equal to 1 if you want to store more than 1 characters.

[image]